# how to handle loader manager onLoadFinished method for three different generic list classes in output

Tags: java, android

i  have three Generic Classes of list

```
1 List< Board >
2 List< Class >
3 List< Subject >
```

during run time i can return any type of list how would i get particular list and display it?

```
@Override
 public Loader<List<Board>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String s=null;
    if (args!=null)
   s = args.getString("string_board_id");
    if (id==1) {
        return new BoardLoader(this, boardUrl);
    }
    if (id==2){
        return new ClassLoader(this, boardUrl,s);
    }
    return null;
 }

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Board>> loader, List<Board> data) {

    if (data !=null && data.size() != 0){
        boardAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
    else{
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"problem with board  list ");
    }

  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a new question then [create a new question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't edit an existing answer on this question to replace it entirely with a new question.

Comment: i am blocked to ask new questions in stackoverflow so the suggest me to edit your questions to remove the ban

Comment: You should edit your actual questions to improve them to get more up votes so the ban is removed. You shouldn't be replacing the *answers* to your questions with new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing 3 callbacks on Activity, make 3 `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Type>` objects. Use these objects when instad of reference to activity.

Use `loader.getId()` inside `onLoadFinished()` to see which loader finished in case you want to use a loader callback with 2 loaders.

Something like this:

```
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> mStringCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {

    }
};
```

Comment: i get the `loader.getId();`cpart but i am still confuse what should i write in  `implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Object>> ` or `implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Board>>` or `implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Class>> `

Comment: None of those. Make 3 callback objects like did and pass those objects instead of `this` in `LoaderManager.initLoder` or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

this is my Home Activity

```
package com.directionclasses.directionclasses;


import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Object>> {

public static final String LOG_TAG = HomeActivity.class.getName();
Spinner spinner;
Spinner spinnerClass;
Spinner spinnerSubject;
private static final int mBoardLoaderManager=1;
private static final int mClassLoaderManager=2;
private static final int mSubjectLoaderManager=3;
private static final String boardUrl = "http://directionclasses.com/Android/selectBoard.php";
private static final String classUrl = "http://directionclasses.com/Android/selectClass.php";
private static final String subjectUrl = "http://directionclasses.com/Android/selectSubject.php";
BoardAdapter boardAdapter = null;
ClassAdapter classAdapter = null;
SubjectAdapter subjectAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar mToolBar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    //  mToolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mToolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);

    android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager=getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(mBoardLoaderManager,null,this);


    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinnerClass = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinnerSubject = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    boardAdapter = new BoardAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Board>());
    classAdapter = new ClassAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Class>());
    subjectAdapter = new SubjectAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Subject>());
    spinner.setAdapter(boardAdapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Board board = boardAdapter.getItem(position);
            int board_id = board.getBoard_id();
            if (board_id != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "jai ho" + board_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String string_board_id = String.valueOf(board_id);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("string_board_id", string_board_id);
                android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager=getLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.initLoader(mClassLoaderManager,b,HomeActivity.this);


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "jai ho with no id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Object>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String s=null;
    if (args!=null) {
        s = args.getString("string_board_id");
    }
    if (id==1) {
        return new BoardLoader(this, boardUrl);
    }
    if (id==2){
        return new ClassLoader(this, classUrl,s);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Object>> loader, List<Object> data) {
    int loader_id=loader.getId();
    if (loader_id==1){
        if (data !=null && data.size() != 0){
            List<Board> mythings = (List<Board>) (Object) data;
            boardAdapter.addAll(mythings);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"problem with board  list ");
        }
    }
    if (loader_id==2){
        if (data !=null && data.size() != 0){
            List<Class> mythings = (List<Class>) (Object) data;
            classAdapter.addAll(mythings);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"problem with class  list ");
        }
    }
    if (loader_id==3){
        if (data !=null && data.size() != 0){
            List<Subject> mythings = (List<Subject>) (Object) data;
            subjectAdapter.addAll(mythings);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"problem with subject  list ");
        }
    }



}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Object>> loader) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"this is the on Load Reset method");
   // boardAdapter.clear();
}



}
```

this is my BoardLoader.java file

```
package com.directionclasses.directionclasses;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class BoardLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {

private static final String LOG_TAG = BoardLoader.class.getName();
private String mUrl;
public BoardLoader(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    mUrl = url;

}
@Override
public List<Board> loadInBackground() {


    ArrayList<Board> boards1 = new ArrayList<Board>();
    URL url1 = null;
    try {
        url1 = new URL(mUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "this is url malformed exception");
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String text = null;
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.flush();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        text = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    boards1 = featuresExtractFromJson(text);

    return boards1;
}
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}

private ArrayList<Board> featuresExtractFromJson(String JsonResponse) {


    ArrayList<Board> results = new ArrayList<Board>();


    try {
        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(JsonResponse);

        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = root.getJSONObject(i);
            String board_id = jsonObject.getString("board_id");
            String board_name = jsonObject.getString("board_name");
            int parse_board_id = Integer.parseInt(board_id);
            results.add(new Board(parse_board_id, board_name));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Json execption");
    }

    return results;
}
}
```

this is my Board Adapter.java File

```
public class BoardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Board> {


public BoardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Board> boards) {
    super(context, 0, boards);
}

public BoardAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, ArrayList<Board> boards) {
    super(context, resource);
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

 @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,  @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    Board board = getItem(position);
    int board_id = board.getBoard_id();
    String board_name = board.getBoard_name();

    TextView text_name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    text_name.setText(board_name);
  //  TextView text_id = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
   // text_id.setText(board_id+"");
    return listItemView;


}
}
```

This is my ClassLoader.java File

```
public class ClassLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {
private static final String LOG_TAG = ClassLoader.class.getName();
private String mUrl;
private String borad_id=null;
public ClassLoader(Context context, String url,String borad_id1 ) {
    super(context);
    mUrl = url;
    borad_id=borad_id1;

}
@Override
public Object loadInBackground() {
    String data = null;
    try {
        data = URLEncoder.encode("board_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(borad_id, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<Class> boards1 = new ArrayList<Class>();
    URL url1 = null;
    try {
        url1 = new URL(mUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "this is url malformed exception");
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String text = null;
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url1.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        text = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    boards1 = featuresExtractFromJson(text);

    return boards1;
}
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}
private ArrayList<Class> featuresExtractFromJson(String JsonResponse) {


    ArrayList<Class> results = new ArrayList<Class>();


    try {
        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(JsonResponse);

        for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = root.getJSONObject(i);
            String calss_id = jsonObject.getString("calss_id");
            String class_name = jsonObject.getString("class_name");
            String board_id = jsonObject.getString("board_id");
            int parse_board_id = Integer.parseInt(board_id);
            int parse_class_id = Integer.parseInt(calss_id);
            results.add(new Class(parse_class_id, class_name, parse_board_id));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Json execption");
    }

    return results;
}
}
```

This is my ClassAdapter.java file

```
public class ClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Class> {

public static final String LOG_TAG = ClassAdapter.class.getName();
public ClassAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Class> classes) {
    super(context, 0, classes);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }
    Class classes = getItem(position);
    int class_id = classes.getClass_id();
    String class_name = classes.getClass_name();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"string class_name"+class_name);
    TextView text_name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    text_name.setText(class_name);
    //  TextView text_id = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    // text_id.setText(board_id+"");
    return listItemView;


}
}
```

after this code my board value is coming from sever.u can see in the link below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RObl.png)

but oniteemclick my class value is fetching respective to its board it from server i have seen them by debugging my application. but my clas value is not displaying in my class spinner.